# How to debug vague Entity Framework "Unable to set field/property" error?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I'm new to EntityFramework and have inherited a project using it to perform what should be a very simple CRUD operation.

Instead when I try to update one column I get the following error on .SaveChanges():

> Unable to set field/property table1 on entity type 
>   System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[Project1.Repository.table2, 
>   Project1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. See InnerException 
>   for details.

The InnerException is null.

I am trying to update table1, table2 has a foreign key to table1, but I'm not trying to update that table at all at this point. My question is, what can I do to find out what the actual problem is here? I have literally no idea how to progress on this. At this point it seems my options are delete the EF model and try to build it again myself, or just bin the whole thing and just use SQL to do it.

Comment: bin the whole thing :) ... ok, you can run SQLServer's trace tool to see what SQL is being generated and run. Take the SQL and run it manually to see if you get a SQL error that might give you a hint of the problem.

Comment: Maybe the error message is a bit vague - it could give you more clues. But it is telling you that it is Unable to set field/property table1. So there must be something wrong with the table1 property. Is it a Collection or a List? Can you post the table2 code?

Comment: Yes, there was something wrong with the table1 property, thanks!

Comment: The property linking table1 to table2 was an ICollection, and I had added a primary key to table2 (which previously was missing a PK, and that itself was causing problems with EF), making the relationship 1-1 instead of 1-many. Removing the ICollection fixed the problem. Thanks!